# Make "and" between author names lower case

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I am using [apalike2.bst](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4004629/apalike2.bst) for my reference list. All author names including the "AND" in between come out in small caps. How do I change the "AND" to lowercase "and"?

Example:
NUNNENKAMP, PETER AND SPATZ, JULIUS (2004). FDI and economic growth in developing economies: how relevant are host-economy and industry characteristics. Transnational Corporations, 13(3):52–86.

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={},yysep={;},notesep={:}} 
\bibliographystyle{Classes/apalike2}
\begin{document}

blabla \citep{Nunnenkamp2004} blablba.

\bibliography{References/references}
\end{document}
```

My bib entry:

```
@Article{Nunnenkamp2004,
Title                    = {{FDI} and economic growth in developing economies: how relevant are host-economy and industry characteristics},
Author                   = {Nunnenkamp, Peter and Spatz, Julius},
Journal                  = {Transnational Corporations},
Year                     = {2004},
Number                   = {3},
Pages                    = {52-86},
Volume                   = {13}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sorry about this. I added an example now.